# Vector too wide

Tags: equations, vector

I am trying to include a very large vector in my tex document. However, the vector is too wide and cuts in the right side. I want to 'shift' it a little bit to the left so it fits to the site without any linebreaks. Does anyone have an idea of how to do it?
[image]

The code:

```
$$\frac{\partial f_{1}}{\partial \boldsymbol{y}}=    \left(\begin{array}{c} -\frac{x_{1}+\frac{x_{4}\,x_{5}\,\left(x_{7}+2\,y_{1}\right)}{\left(x_{6}+y_{1}\right)\,\left(x_{7}+y_{1}\right)}+\frac{x_{4}\,x_{5}\,x_{7}\,y_{1}}{\left(x_{6}+y_{1}\right)\,{\left(x_{7}+y_{1}\right)}^2}-\frac{x_{4}\,x_{5}\,y_{1}\,\left(x_{7}+2\,y_{1}\right)}{{\left(x_{6}+y_{1}\right)}^2\,\left(x_{7}+y_{1}\right)}}{x_{3}+x_{4}\,\left(\frac{x_{6}}{{\left(x_{6}+y_{1}\right)}^2}+\frac{x_{7}}{{\left(x_{7}+y_{1}\right)}^2}\right)}-\frac{x_{4}\,\left(\frac{2\,x_{6}}{{\left(x_{6}+y_{1}\right)}^3}+\frac{2\,x_{7}}{{\left(x_{7}+y_{1}\right)}^3}\right)\,\left(x_{1}\,\left(y_{1}-y_{3}\right)+\frac{x_{4}\,x_{5}\,y_{1}\,\left(x_{7}+2\,y_{1}\right)}{\left(x_{6}+y_{1}\right)\,\left(x_{7}+y_{1}\right)}\right)}{{\left(x_{3}+x_{4}\,\left(\frac{x_{6}}{{\left(x_{6}+y_{1}\right)}^2}+\frac{x_{7}}{{\left(x_{7}+y_{1}\right)}^2}\right)\right)}^2}\\ 0\\ \frac{x_{1}}{x_{3}+x_{4}\,\left(\frac{x_{6}}{{\left(x_{6}+y_{1}\right)}^2}+\frac{x_{7}}{{\left(x_{7}+y_{1}\right)}^2}\right)} \end{array}\right)$$

$$\frac{\partial f_{2}}{\partial \boldsymbol{y}}=     \left(\begin{array}{c} 0\\ -\frac{x_{8}+\frac{x_{10}\,x_{11}\,\left(x_{7}+2\,y_{2}\right)}{\left(x_{6}+y_{2}\right)\,\left(x_{7}+y_{2}\right)}+\frac{x_{7}\,x_{10}\,x_{11}\,y_{2}}{\left(x_{6}+y_{2}\right)\,{\left(x_{7}+y_{2}\right)}^2}-\frac{x_{10}\,x_{11}\,y_{2}\,\left(x_{7}+2\,y_{2}\right)}{{\left(x_{6}+y_{2}\right)}^2\,\left(x_{7}+y_{2}\right)}}{x_{9}+x_{10}\,\left(\frac{x_{6}}{{\left(x_{6}+y_{2}\right)}^2}+\frac{x_{7}}{{\left(x_{7}+y_{2}\right)}^2}\right)}-\frac{x_{10}\,\left(\frac{2\,x_{6}}{{\left(x_{6}+y_{2}\right)}^3}+\frac{2\,x_{7}}{{\left(x_{7}+y_{2}\right)}^3}\right)\,\left(x_{8}\,\left(y_{2}-y_{3}\right)+\frac{x_{10}\,x_{11}\,y_{2}\,\left(x_{7}+2\,y_{2}\right)}{\left(x_{6}+y_{2}\right)\,\left(x_{7}+y_{2}\right)}\right)}{{\left(x_{9}+x_{10}\,\left(\frac{x_{6}}{{\left(x_{6}+y_{2}\right)}^2}+\frac{x_{7}}{{\left(x_{7}+y_{2}\right)}^2}\right)\right)}^2}\\ \frac{x_{8}}{x_{9}+x_{10}\,\left(\frac{x_{6}}{{\left(x_{6}+y_{2}\right)}^2}+\frac{x_{7}}{{\left(x_{7}+y_{2}\right)}^2}\right)} \end{array}\right)$$
```

I think the package which might apply here is the 'amsthm' package.
The document class I am using is
`\documentclass[parskip,headsepline]{scrreprt}`

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please tell us which document class you employ and how wide the text block is, and please show the code that gives rise to the screenshot shown above.

Answer (score 1):

The vectors contain 6 very large `\frac` terms. I suggest you pursue a two-stage process to typeset the vectors: First, give expressions for them in terms of the 6 large fractional expressions; then, state what these 6 large expressions are.

In the following code, note that I've gotten rid of all 52 `\,` spacers all 52 `\left` and all 52 `\right` auto-sizing directives. I did have to introduce 12 `\Bigl` and `\Bigr` directives each.

[image]

```
\documentclass[parskip,headsepline]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{amsmath}  % for 'pmatrix' and 'align*' environments
\usepackage{bm}       % for '\bm' macro
\usepackage{booktabs} % for '\addlinespace' macro
\begin{document}

\[
\frac{\partial f_{1}}{\partial \bm{y}}=    
\begin{pmatrix}
-A_1-A_2 \\ 0 \\ A_3
\end{pmatrix}
\quad\text{and}\quad
\frac{\partial f_{2}}{\partial \bm{y}}=
\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\ -B_1-B_2 \\ B_3
\end{pmatrix}
\]
where
\begin{align*}
A_1 &= \frac{x_{1}+\frac{x_{4}x_{5}(x_{7}+2y_{1})}{(x_{6}+y_{1})(x_{7}+y_{1})}+\frac{x_{4}x_{5}x_{7}y_{1}}{(x_{6}+y_{1}){(x_{7}+y_{1})}^2}-\frac{x_{4}x_{5}y_{1}(x_{7}+2y_{1})}{{(x_{6}+y_{1})}^2(x_{7}+y_{1})}}{x_{3}+x_{4}\Bigl(\frac{x_{6}}{{(x_{6}+y_{1})}^2}+\frac{x_{7}}{{(x_{7}+y_{1})}^2}\Bigr)} \\
\addlinespace % a bit of vertical whitespace
A_2 &= \frac{x_{4}\Bigl(\frac{2x_{6}}{{(x_{6}+y_{1})}^3}+\frac{2x_{7}}{{(x_{7}+y_{1})}^3}\Bigr)\Bigl(x_{1}(y_{1}-y_{3})+\frac{x_{4}x_{5}y_{1}(x_{7}+2y_{1})}{(x_{6}+y_{1})(x_{7}+y_{1})}\Bigr)}{{\Bigl(x_{3}+x_{4}\Bigl(\frac{x_{6}}{{(x_{6}+y_{1})}^2}+\frac{x_{7}}{{(x_{7}+y_{1})}^2}\Bigr)\Bigr)}^2} \\ 
\addlinespace
A_3 &= \frac{x_{1}}{x_{3}+x_{4}\Bigl(\frac{x_{6}}{{(x_{6}+y_{1})}^2}+\frac{x_{7}}{{(x_{7}+y_{1})}^2}\Bigr)} \\
\addlinespace
B_1 &= \frac{x_{8}+\frac{x_{10}x_{11}(x_{7}+2y_{2})}{(x_{6}+y_{2})(x_{7}+y_{2})}+\frac{x_{7}x_{10}x_{11}y_{2}}{(x_{6}+y_{2}){(x_{7}+y_{2})}^2}-\frac{x_{10}x_{11}y_{2}(x_{7}+2y_{2})}{{(x_{6}+y_{2})}^2(x_{7}+y_{2})}}{x_{9}+x_{10}\Bigl(\frac{x_{6}}{{(x_{6}+y_{2})}^2}+\frac{x_{7}}{{(x_{7}+y_{2})}^2}\Bigr)} \\
\addlinespace
B_2 &= \frac{x_{10}\Bigl(\frac{2x_{6}}{{(x_{6}+y_{2})}^3}+\frac{2x_{7}}{{(x_{7}+y_{2})}^3}\Bigr)\Bigl(x_{8}(y_{2}-y_{3})+\frac{x_{10}x_{11}y_{2}(x_{7}+2y_{2})}{(x_{6}+y_{2})(x_{7}+y_{2})}\Bigr)}{{\Bigl(x_{9}+x_{10}\Bigl(\frac{x_{6}}{{(x_{6}+y_{2})}^2}+\frac{x_{7}}{{(x_{7}+y_{2})}^2}\Bigr)\Bigr)}^2}\\ 
\addlinespace
B_3 &= \frac{x_{8}}{x_{9}+x_{10}\Bigl(\frac{x_{6}}{{(x_{6}+y_{2})}^2}+\frac{x_{7}}{{(x_{7}+y_{2})}^2}\Bigr)} 
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, but this is not what I am trying to do. Since the equations are only exceeding the page's width by milli meters, I would like to keep them as a whole

Comment: @youneedtoread1 - The width of the text block is certainly a very important piece of information. Please feel free to share it.

Comment: I guess `\geometry{left=2.75cm,right= 2.75cm,top=2.5cm,}` is the information you asked for?

Comment: Replacing the placeholders `A_1`, `A_2`, etc with the big expressions shown above  will make the equations protrude massively into the right-hand margin. The only piece of good news is that they won't actually spill over past the page.